# Correct place to load an extension in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

My hosting provider does not have `curl` extension enabled by default, however, I can load it using `dl()`.

What would be the correct place in `WordPress` to load the extension so that it could use `curl` for `wp_remote_*` functions?

I'd like it to survive the possible upgrades of `WordPress` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The earliest hook I know of is `init`. My recommendation would be to build this as a plug-in (so that it will survive upgrades) and do the following:

```
add_action('init', 'load_curl_functions');

function load_curl_functions() {
    //Use dl() to load curl
}
```

---- EDIT ----

It looks like there are some hooks that fire before `init`.  I recommend trying to hook to `load_textdomain` instead.  This is the hook that loads language and translation functions (the only hook that fires earlier is `muplugins_loaded` which might not work in non-mu installations).

So: `add_action('load_textdomain', 'load_curl_functions');` should load your curl extension before doing anything else ...

Comment: or if you are doing this for something in the theme. Add that to your functions page.

Comment: Actually, I only need curl extension when loading the dashboard (it is required by Google Analytics plugin's admin mode). Wouldn't loading `curl.so` on each page view be much of an overhead?

Comment: In that case, use the `plugins_loaded` hook.  It's the first hook to fire for an admin page request.